# Query GCP monitoring API for current postgres connections query?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-monitoring

We can see the postgres connections in the GCP console, so we presume that it can be queried via the monitoring API. The console gives us this MQL query:

```
fetch cloudsql_database
| metric 'cloudsql.googleapis.com/database/postgresql/num_backends'
| filter (resource.database_id == 'my-project-id:my-database-id')
| group_by 1m, [value_num_backends_mean: mean(value.num_backends)]
| every 1m
```

The monitoring API https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/query

says that the `query` parameter is required and the query is in the monitoring query language format. However, when I "Try this API" and attempt to set the query to what I got from the console above, I get an error that "Unexpected character encountered" for the `|` character. How can I properly format the query in a way to get the result I am looking for? I have looked through the [Retrieving data with timeSeries.query](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/mql/qn-from-api#ql-timeseries-query) documentation, and it does not mention the need to escape such characters.

Comment: Do you recieve an error when you remove those characters? If you do, make sure to edit the original post with that info

Answer (score 1):

So MQL is more for querying within the Monitoring Metrics Explorer, and the Monitoring API uses a different kind of language for its filtering. Something along the lines of

```
resource.type = "the_resource_type"
resource.labels.a_label_for_the_resource_type = "label_value"
```

And this is what you would use for querying with the API instead of MQL.

An exa will look something like this:

```
metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/usage_time" AND
    metric.labels.instance_name = "my-instance-name"
```

https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/v3/filters

You may also want to look into using [time series list](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/api/ref_v3/rest/v3/projects.timeSeries/list) as another possible API method, as this does not require MQL.